# google sign in with flutter and firebase auth

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to implement Google Signin in my flutter app and I don't know what I am doing wrong, a little help is appriciated.

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
GoogleSignInAccount? currentUser;
googleLogin(context, color) async {
try {
  final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();

  // loading(context, color);

  // I am not able to go beyond here
  
  if (googleUser == null) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    return;
  }
  currentUser = googleUser;
  String? access, id;
  await googleUser.authentication.then((value) async {
    if (value != null) {
      access = value.accessToken;
      id = value.idToken;
    }
  });
  UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
      .signInWithCredential(
          GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken: id, accessToken: access));
  print('name: ${currentUser!.displayName}');
} catch (e) {}
```

}

I am stuck at the line, comment after that, what happens in the app is that dialogue box of accounts for google appears and when I select account, it disappears and nothing happens.

As for terminal, it displays

```
An Observatory debugger and profiler on RMX3363 is available at: 
http://127.0.0.1:50786/aiMRW_z817c=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on RMX3363 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?    
uri=http://127.0.0.1:50786/aiMRW_z817c=/
V/OplusZoomWindowDecorViewHelper(24796): setLastReportedMergedConfiguration                 
mZoomDisplayHeight: 2400 getDecorView.19495807
D/hw-ProcessState(24796): Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid 
argument
D/SurfaceComposerClient(24796): VRR [FRTC] client handle [bufferId:18446744073709551615         
framenumber:0] [ffffffff, ffffffff]
D/SurfaceComposerClient(24796): VRR [FRTC] client handle [bufferId:18446744073709551615 
framenumber:0] [ffffffff, ffffffff]
E/Parcel  (24796): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
V/OplusZoomWindowDecorViewHelper(24796): setLastReportedMergedConfiguration     
mZoomDisplayHeight: 2400 getDecorView.200652440
D/SurfaceComposerClient(24796): VRR [FRTC] client handle [bufferId:18446744073709551615 
framenumber:0] [ffffffff, ffffffff]
V/OplusZoomWindowDecorViewHelper(24796): removeZoomView
I/Quality (24796): Skipped: false 1
```

A little help is appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you followed steps in doc?

Answer (score 0):

I realized I forgot to add SHA1 and SHA256 at firebase, added those and it worked.